# Sublime-Text-style autocomplete in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, sublime-text-2, autocomplete

I know that Word has a built-in autocomplete function. As far as I know, though, apart from dates, if I want a particular word to come up as a suggestion, I need to have it saved as an auto text. Is it possible to have an autocomplete, similar to the one in Sublime Text 2, where the autocomplete suggestions are based on words, already mentioned in the particular document. For example, if I have a blank document, than write the sentence `This is an example sentence.` and next start typing the letters `se`, than the word `sentence` should pop up as a suggestion.

Comment: A macro would be the way to go about this, you would want it to learn each word that you type and add it as an autotext entry. Sounds a tad complex but very possible, try googling some starting points for the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Word cannot accomplish this.,This feature is available in [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/). For more information see [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/guide/word_completion.html) and [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/guide/word_completion_adjust.html) for fine-tuning it.